# cv2.error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, opencv, base64

I was trying to do video streaming using sockets in python 3. I was reading frames continuously using imutils.video.FileVideoStream and used base64 encoding to send images from client to another client via a server. Here's my Send() function:-

**SEND**

```
def Send():
fvs = FileVideoStream(0).start()
time.sleep(1.0)
while True:
    frame = fvs.read()

    # cvImage = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(frame), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # pil = Image.fromarray(cvImage)
    # b = io.BytesIO()
    # pil.save(b, 'jpeg')
    # imgBytes = b.getvalue()

    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)

    length = str(len(jpg_as_text))
    # print("client is sending...")
    client.sendall(length.encode(encoding='utf_8'))
    client.sendall(jpg_as_text)
```

**RECIEVE**

```
def Recieve():
print("Client is recieving...")
while True:
    length = int(client.recv(2 * BufferSize).decode("utf-8"))
    print("length:- {}".format(length))
    data = b''
    while True:
        if len(data) < length:
            to_read = length - len(data)
            data += client.recv(BufferSize if to_read > BufferSize else to_read)
        else:
            break

    # pilBytes = io.BytesIO(data)
    # pilBytes.seek(0)
    # pilImage = Image.open(pilBytes)
    # cvImage = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pilImage), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    # cv2.imshow("Video", np.array(pilImage))
    print("data length:- {}".format(len(data)))
    img = base64.b64decode(data)
    npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
    cv2.imshow("Stream", source)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And finally here's my main part of server.py

**SERVER**

```
def ClientConnection(client):
length = int(client.recv(2 * BufferSize).decode("utf-8"))
SendLength(client, str(length))
while True:
    # print("In client Connections...")
    receivingBuffer = client.recv(BufferSize)
    if not receivingBuffer:
        break
    data = b''
    if len(data) < length:

        to_read = length - len(data)
        data = client.recv(BufferSize if to_read > BufferSize else to_read)
        length -= len(data)
    broadcast(client, data)
```

Please help as in where I went wrong. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I printed every variable in "Recieve()", i.e img, npimg and source, All of them are coming out to be okay except source variable, which is coming out to be None, When I tried to decode the image from bytes on my localhost, all the variables are coming out to be of similar dimensions and type except source variable. source variable is coming out to be None. Please help me out.

**EDIT AGAIN**
here's my code after applying some changes to server side:-

**SERVER**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM   
from threading import Thread

HOST = "192.168.43.215"
PORT = 4000
BufferSize = 4096
addresses = {}

def Connections():
while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print("{} is connected!!".format(addr))
    addresses[client] = addr
    Thread(target=ClientConnection, args=(client, )).start()

def ClientConnection(client):
length = int(client.recv(BufferSize).decode("utf-8"))
SendLength(client, str(length))
data = b''
while length > BufferSize:
    length -= BufferSize
    data += client.recv(BufferSize)
data += client.recv(length)
broadcast (client,data)
print (length)
print("Frame sent ")

def SendLength(clientSocket, length):
for client in addresses:
    if client != clientSocket:
        print("sending length:- {}".format(length))
        client.send(length.encode("utf-8"))

def broadcast(clientSocket, data_to_be_sent):
for client in addresses:
    if client != clientSocket:
        print("Broadcasting...")
        client.sendall(data_to_be_sent)
server = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    server.bind((HOST, PORT))
except OSError:
    print("Server Busy")

server.listen(2)
print("Waiting for connection..")
AcceptThread = Thread(target=Connections)
AcceptThread.start()
AcceptThread.join()
```

**CLIENT**

```
import cv2
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import base64
import numpy as np
import time

def Recieve():
print("Client is recieving...")
while True:
    length = int(client.recv(2 * BufferSize).decode("utf-8"))
    print("length:- {}".format(length))
    data = b''
    while True:
        if len(data) < length:
            to_read = length - len(data)
            data += client.recv(BufferSize if to_read > BufferSize else to_read)
        else:
            break

    print("data length:- {}".format(len(data)))
    img = base64.b64decode(data)
    npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
    cv2.imshow("Stream", source)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

def Send():
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(1.0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(frame)

    length = str(len(jpg_as_text))
    client.sendall(length.encode(encoding='utf_8'))
    client.sendall(jpg_as_text)
```

And finally to start threads:-

```
RecieveThread = Thread(target=Recieve).start() 
SendThread = Thread(target=Send).start()
print("Waiting for connection..")
AcceptThread = Thread(target=Connections)
AcceptThread.start()
AcceptThread.join()
```

Comment: Seems like `imdecode` fails, I suppose you're corrupting the data in someway somewhere in the process. Try it with some small synthetic images, and validate that you're feeding `imdecode` the exact same thing that came out of `imencode`.

Comment: I tried encoding and decoding image data from bytes on my local host itself and everything worked out smoothly, but when I printed "source" variable on client machine, it came out to be None. I am not able to figure out where my data has gone corrupt.

Comment: OK, Can you turn that code into a [mcve] -- i.e. something we can copy/paste into a file (well, two files in this case) and run (without needing any modifications, such as adding missing imports, etc) in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I tried to paste only relevant part of the code, hope it helps...

Comment: I'm sorry, but notice how I said [mcve], and even gave an explanation -- what you posted still misses that target. "Minimal" means the least amount of code needed to reproduce the problem, including no useless comments (I count at least 16). It also means the least amount of dependencies -- right now you need `FileVideoStream`, can you reproduce the error with a synthetic image, such as 16x16 with each pixel different shade of gray? Do you need to send multiple images, or does it break on the first one? | "Complete" means, "no missing imports" (I count at least 4 on cursory glance).

Comment: Take your time and reduce your code to the absolute minimum that still exhibits the problem. The reason this is requested, is that it's an essential step in debugging a problem, and by doing so you learn those skills (and often end up  identifying the issue yourself). The smaller the amount of code, the easier for you to debug it. Last, but not least, if you're asking others to help you fix your problem, it would be courteous to do the most you can to help them reproduce the problem (meaning, don't make us spend time to just make the program run -- help us help you ;) )

Comment: The error message is an assertion inside the `imshow` function meaning that you the image you give to it is empty.

Comment: @DanMašek as I am trying to video stream using webcam I need to read frames continuously and send to a server from where it goes to all other different clients. I tried to produce minimal and complete code. Please consider. The problem is what Jhon_Sharp1318 told, I'm receiving empty image even after sending data, and I cannot figure out where my data has gone corrupt.